# Criar botões em um layout de grade

Tags: android, xml, app, layout

Gostaria de saber como é possível fazer uma *activity* como um menu em grade... Qual tipo de layout é mais aconselhável? Um *relative*, linear, *grid* ou *table*?

Exemplo do que necessito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sem a necessidade dos banners, apenas o menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O *layout* próprio para grades é o [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

Veja uma exemplo de grade com 2 colunas e 2 linas:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".GridXMLActivity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:text="Button" />   
</GridLayout>
```

**Resultado**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo assim, bastar ajustar as configurações devidas como centralização de *views*, uso de `ImaveView`, etc.

Comment: obrigado pela a iluminação ^^

Comment: @RenatoPedrozo se a resposta te ajudou resolvendo seu problema e quiser valida-la, fique a vontade =D